# typedef is used on same struct twice

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to understand struct usage in a piece of code. It is very confusing to me. looks like typedef is used twice on same struct. please can anyone help me understand why this code has typedef twice. is there any way to simplify this code. 
thanks so much for your time.

```
typedef struct {
city_t* cities; 
int count;      
cost_t cost;    
} tour_struct;
typedef tour_struct* tour_t;


typedef struct {
tour_t* list;
int list_sz;
int list_alloc;
}  stack_struct;
typedef stack_struct* my_stack_t;
```

Comment: `tour_struct` is a struct.  `tour_t` is a `tour_struct *`, that is, `tour_t` is a pointer to the struct typedef'ed as `tour_struct`

Comment: Note that names that [end in `_t` are reserved on POSIX systems](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02).  Also, naming a pointer type `*_t` is perverse at best.

Answer (score 3):

The first `typedef` gives the (anonymous) struct a typename. The second `typedef` defines a type of a *pointer* to the other.

```
tour_struct tour; // declares a struct.
tour_t ptr; // declares a pointer to a struct.
```

Answer (score 0):

First typedef is used in a typical way to declare structs in C.
I guess You are referring to second typedef:
    typedef tour_struct* tour_t;
it is used because here is declared "another name" (alias) for **a pointer** to aboved declared struct. This is why second typedef has been used.

Comment: can i change my code to this and still have same meaning.    struct tour_struct {
   city_t* cities; 
   int count;      
   cost_t cost;    
};
 
 
 struct stack_struct{
   struct tour_struct *list;
   int list_sz;
   int list_alloc;
};
struct  stack_struct *my_stack_t;

Answer (score 0):

using a `*` after a known type in `typedef` simply defines a pointer to that type.

```
typedef stack_struct* my_stack_t;
```

will define a pointer to `stack_struct` and will call it `my_stack_t`.